# Mono + XSP: WebService example does not work

Tags: web-server, mono

There have been questions quite similar to this one, but I could not find any solution. So excuse me for asking it again.

I'm running Debian Linux and I installed Mono. Once I started the [sample WebService](http://www.mono-project.com/Writing_a_WebService) with the XSP (or XSP4) server, I can not access it neither locally nor from anywhere else in the network.

The *.asmx file is in a folder from which I also start the XSP server.

Here's the sample code:

```
using System;
using System.Web.Services;

namespace MathService
{
    [WebService (Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/NumberService")]
    public class MathService : WebService
    {
        [WebMethod]
        public int AddNumbers (int number1, int number2)
        {
            return number1 + number2;
        }

        [WebMethod]
        public int SubtractNumbers (int number1, int number2)
        {
            return number1 - number2;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you get any console output from `xsp`?

Comment: Yes, saying that it started correctly on which IP adress, which port and which root directory. I guess it's a problem of the hardware. I'm running a RaspberryPi with hard-float Rasbian/Debian "Wheezy". I found some comments saying that .NET mono application might have issues with that. So I'm trying the soft-float version right now.

Comment: Are you able to run the `asp.net-examples` sample application?  I am also running hard-float Wheezy and I can't get the example application to run.  The TCP connection immediately closes without sending any data or the connection just hangs.  Upon first connection the server does display `Application_Start`

Comment: I got the same problems as you mentioned. As far as I understand, it's because of the hard-float ARM. I was trying to setup webservices with C++ using Apache AXIS or using Apache Thrift for typed-conform communication, but they are all much too complicated.

Answer (score 1):

Mono now supports armhf.  As of 12/8/2013 you need to build mono from its git repository (master).

```
git clone git://github.com/mono/mono.git

cd mono
./autogen.sh --prefix=/usr/local
make
make install
```

Now download and build XSP from its git repository:

```
git clone https://github.com/mono/xsp.git

cd xsp
./autogen.sh

/configure --prefix=/usr/local
make 
make install
```

Comment: Does this fix the problem?